# How can I see logs of all calls made to the Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I request data from Firebase, whatever language or location, I typically send a get request to a `node`, for instance:

```
/posts/foo/boo
```

Is it possible to view somewhere all the logs of the requests sent to Firebase? The reason I am asking is because I am trying to figure out my high costs for Firebase, as I don't see where the requests are made from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no persistent log of such data, but you can [use the database profiler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile) to get a log of listens as they are happening.

Also see this recent blog post of someone [using the profiler to troubleshoot a performance problem on their database](https://pragli.com/blog/fixing-usage-firebase-real-time-database/).

Comment: Btw, when you say “listens”, does that include calls from a backend, eg firebase to a single node (GET only once)?

Comment: Yes, those would be included. Let me know if you're having trouble making it work.

Comment: Works great and confirms the excessive download that I am noticing. Unfortunately havent figured out where it comes from. I am suspecting its related to the cloud functions listeners to the RT Database, as am seeing the $wildcard tag in the nodes.

Comment: Cloud Functions triggers don't show up in your usage or profiler. They're not implemented as listeners, but as events that trigger on writes to the database. If course if you use listeners *inside* your Cloud Functions code, those would show up.

Comment: Good to know, what about the $wildcard tag in the node?

Comment: Hard to say, and definitely not an area I have the most experience with. It might be worth posting a new question (including the output you get from the profiler), to see if somebody can explain what it means.